# MongoDB + node: not authorized to execute command (sometimes works, sometimes doesn't)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, restify

I'm facing a problem with my MongoDB environment - the setup is as follows:

My node app provides a restify API which handles user registration (look up if a user exists in a collection based on his mail, and if not, insert him (note - insert uses bcrypt to hash the passwords, so probably is a bit slower)). It uses restify and Mongoose ORM.

A second benchmark script (also written in node, running on the same machine) accesses this restify API using HTTP PUT.

I'm starting around 20-30 of these requests in the benchmark (with random data) and only some of the API requests correctly insert the new users. For the other, MongoDB produces errors similar to the following:

> not authorized on ... to execute command { find: "users", filter: { mail: "rroouksl@hddngrau.de" } }
>
> not authorized on ... to execute command { insert: "users", documents: [ { ... } ], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w: 1 } }

Some other users get inserted perfectly fine. Especially with a low number of requests at the same time (1-5) no problems occur. Shouldn't Mongo be able to handle these "low" amount of requests? Is it a problem because it's running on the same machine? Hasn't the user I created in Mongo for this project got enough txns/second allowed?

Best regards,
Zahlii

Comment: I don't know much about Mongo, but is it possible that read or write locks are causing these errors? Maybe check this post for write failures and locking: https://www.rainforestqa.com/blog/2012-11-05-mongodb-gotchas-and-how-to-avoid-them/

Comment: I am also facing this issue.Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that mongo was still using the "old" storage engine and not WiredTiger. Since my queries included updating records, the old engine performed collection-based locks which means that the errors were solely based on read-write locks.

I migrated to WiredTiger which performs document-based locking and since then, the database handles many parallel requests without these errors (although sometimes under heavy load they appear again - but this is part of mongo being NoSQL I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Db.authenticate(user, password, function(err, res) {
  // callback
});
```

Also [see the source](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/V0.8.1/lib/mongodb/db.js#L282).